# How to click a div to pop a prompt when prompt value matched php variable then echo content inline

Tags: javascript, php, html, match, echo

but know js, html and css...

Today, I need to protect some contents so need to use server-side code to verify visitor is or not know the "password". If visitor knows the password, then echo the contents to them.

I hope to make the php auto verify when onchange. Such like js onchange event start, run the function -> the condition matched -> return the content.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input-password" placeholder="Input password here...">
<div id="secret-content"><!-- may be place php here to echo the content? If the condition matched --></div>
```

Let's say the password is `qwerty`, when visitor type into the input field matched `qwerty`, the div id="secret-content" will echo / (append?) the content inside the div? And also, when the password matched, the input text field need to hidden.

How to simulate it? Thanks.

Comment: use $_POST and then check if the post value is the correct now

Comment: hi jeff, but use $_POST will likely refresh the web page, it will go back to the top of the page. I need it stay on the same position

Comment: if you don't want to refresh the page use ajax

Comment: _"I need it stay on the same position"_ - then specify the id of the element you want t jump to in the hash portion of the form action attribute.